# Assign Count and Row Values to a Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I want to find two equal and opposite values in a given range and highlight both of them.

Just got know that VBA has Dictionary as well and tried to solve the problem using that.

I don't want to publish working data to a sheet but not sure how to do it like I can do in Python by assigning a list to a Dictionary.

I saw an answer to a similar question but it ignores the fact there might more than 1 entries (like 10,10, -10).

I want to *only* highlight if there is no confusion regarding the pair (the range has 32 and -32 *only*).

So far I have done the basic work:

```
Dim dict As Object
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set rng = Range("AH" & AbsStart & ":AH" & AHEnd)

For Each cl In rng.Cells
    dict(cl.Row) = dict(cl.Row) + 1
Next

Dim VarKey As Variant

For Each VarKey In dict.Keys()
    If dict(VarKey) = 2 Then
        
    
Next
```

Comment: This 'dict(cl.Row) = dict(cl.Row) + 1' probably isn't doing what you think its doing.  In fact, its much better if you don't use this facility of the scripting dictionary and instead write using the .Add method 'dict.add cl.Row, dict(cl.Row) + 1'.    I still don't think this makes sense in the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - using a dictionary to track already-matched cells:

```vb
Sub HiliteMatches()

    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, arr, r As Long, r2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A10") 'for example
    arr = rng.Value
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(r) Then            'cell already flagged?
            For r2 = r + 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
                If Not dict.Exists(r2) Then
                    If arr(r, 1) = -arr(r2, 1) Then
                        dict.Add r2, True
                        rng.Cells(r).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                        rng.Cells(r2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                        Exit For              'stop after one match
                    End If
                End If  'cell not flagged
            Next r2
        End If          'cell not flagged
    Next r

End Sub
```